# How to disable a highchart chart completely

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I am trying to figure out how to disable a chart (pie chart, column chart, etc.) completely but I haven't been able to do it at all. Once I set the whole section within the chart to hidden, part of the chart continues there.

**HTML**

```
<div id="pieChartSection"class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6" id="myPieChart" style="min-width: 500px; height: 350px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</div>
```

Then, at some point on my **JS** I do...

```
document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "hidden";
```

where the **id** is "pieChartSection"

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

** updated answer **

so just as an example, I added a button to your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fv5aos97/23/) demo.

using jQuery, you can add a toggle event like this:

`$('button').click(function(){
    $('#pieChartSection').toggle(function(){`

and then embed the rest of your code within that toggle fuction, as seen in the jsfiddle demo.

I hope this helps!

Cheers

Comment: This is what I got when using a real chart from highchart http://jsfiddle.net/fv5aos97/

Comment: thanks for a more complete example! I'll take a look

Comment: I updated the solution. I hope this more accurately answers your question!